# Unknown formal font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I searched this font letter, a capital T, during some hours and I did not find it. The type of font is formal. The second image is the original source, the flower is not part of the font.

Anyone know which font is? Thanks.

[image: T letter]

[image]

Comment: Hard to ID a font from 1 glyph. Kinda looks similar to https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/sloop-script#fonts-section -- I think using "Formal" may be incorrect. It's clearly a script, but I'm not certain what "formal" would indicate.

Comment: It is a T. Looks like a C but it is really a T. It is the unique letter I have. The rest of the text is another font.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Can you show the other letters? It's almost impossible to identify a font from one letter only.  Are you sure this is a T?  Is this a Latin script, or some other script such as Greek or Cyrillic?  In Latin scripts a T would never look like a C.  There's also a distinct possibility this is not a font.  It's clearly from some embroidery work which may have been made entirely by hand. Not everything is a font you can download.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is from a handmade item I doubt that its from an existing font rather that just Calligraphy from the person who made that . However , That was just my theory and you can check this useful website https://www.whatfontis.com . You can upload photos of fonts and it will tell you the name of it . hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used this font: https://www.etsy.com/es/listing/777952556/fairy-tale-embroidery-font-1-125-15-2-25?ref=yr_purchases

It is not exactly the same, but it is similar.

[image]